# Permalinks & domain name for application

Tags: domains, htaccess

I originally posted this on stackoverflow, then was told it didn't fit. I'm looking for some advice.

I created an application that deals heavily with twitter & permalinks. I have yet to find a domain name for this project. I have a personal domain name `reggi.com`. I was wondering would it be ideal to launch the project under a subdirectory such as `reggi.com/projects/light`. All of the permalinks would stick with this domain. If in the event I find a domain name suitable for the project I can relocate the project but keep all of the permalinks using `reggi.com/projects/light` and route to the new domain name with `.htaccess`. This way none of the links will ever break if I change domains later on or the project busts and I don't want to pay for the domain anymore. I'm going to bitly shorten the links so that on twitter the `reggi.com/projects/light` prefix wont even show.
What do you think I should do?

Answer (score 1):

**Just apply for a domain. It's cheap and will save you headaches later.**

Yes, you can set redirects but a lot of established links will be to the old format. Not that is is much of problem but if you avoid it everything will be consistent.